# AWS-JAVA-SDK: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes

Tags: java, scala, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless

I'm trying to deploy a single lambda function on AWS in scala with SAM-CLI.

It works fine, but when I add the dependency to my build.sbt

```
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.46"
```

The deploy fails and return

```
"Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 53eeb ab6-9377-4a37-b20b-9e55ccbebd72, Extended Request ID: null)"
```

My function is

```
    def handle(request: APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: Context): Response = {
    
    println("handling %s %s, remaining time is %d ms".format(
      request.getHttpMethod, request.getPath, context.getRemainingTimeInMillis) )
    
    println(s"""environment = ${sys.env.getOrElse("env", "n/a")}""")

    val name = request.getPathParameters.get("name")
    Response(s"Hello, $name\n", Map("Content-Type" -> "text/plain"))
  }
  
  case class Response(body: String, headers: Map[String,String], statusCode: Int = 200) {
    def javaHeaders: java.util.Map[String, String] = headers.asJava `enter code here`}
```

And my template.yaml looks like

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Description: >-
  A SAM CLI template for a single-endpoint Hello World Lambda function in Scala

Resources:
  HelloScalaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: HelloScala
      Description: A simple AWS Lambda function in Scala
      Runtime: java8
      Handler: lambda.ApiGatewayProxyHandler
      CodeUri: target/scala-2.12/hello-scala.jar
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 15
      Environment:
        Variables:
          env: staging
      Events:
        Hello:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello/{name}
            Method: GET
        
Outputs:
    ApiURL:
      Description: "API endpoint URL for Prod environment"
      Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/{name}"
```

Anyone has ever experienced something similar?
How would you solve this?

Comment: You really shouldn't add the whole AWS SDK to your lambda function. Only add the library for the services you need. For example - if you need to connect to DynamoDB database, only add the DynamoDB service. Same goes to all AWS services - each service has it's own library

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions have a code size limit. You tried to deploy something which was too big. It looks like you wanted to use something from the AWS SDK but instead of picking the specific module you picked the dependency with everything.

When working with Lambda try to reduce the size of your dependencies.